# Node-webkit: reload page with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, node-webkit

Usually in my web-site I reload page with any parameters in this way:

```
var relaodParam = function(param, value) {
   window.location.href += window.location.origin + "/?" + param + "=" + value;
}
```

I have recently started using node and with nodewebkit to make a webapp.
**Problem:** now code does'nt work anymore.

If my window.location.href was:

```
file://<app_path>/public/index.html
```

When I realod, href began:

```
file:///?<param>=<value>
```

How I could get the same behavior as in normal html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.origin` only returns the origin. Use the `window.location.href` to get the full current URI.

Like `window.location.href += "?" + param + "=" + value;`

This wont work if u already have GET parameters in the url. so for that case u have to cut them of.

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?' + param + '=' + value;
```

be aware that current parameters will just be cut off. But this is the same like in your example!

Comment: thak's for suggest, in the meanwhile I've already solved reloading with correct url.. the problem is that with new url nothing happens :S